# Content is not allowed in trailing section --> SAXParseException in XML file ( Java Spring)

Tags: java, xml, spring

First time trying to run the Spring framework and after downloading and installing the whole spring library ( plus the common login from apache? --> from what I read online) I tried running a spring trial project using this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans- 3.0.xsd">

            <bean id="restaurantBean" class="com.gontuseries.springcore.Restaurant">  </bean>


 </beans>
```

I tried adding the context line in my root ( found on another answer). Other answers said to look for hidden characters in my xml file but... how? ( if that is even the problem).

Here is the error stacktrace:

> "Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Line 10 in XML document from class path resource [SpringConfig.xml] is
>   invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
>   lineNumber: 10; columnNumber: 9; Content is not allowed in trailing
>   section."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Other answers said to look for hidden characters in my xml file but... how?

Yes, that is the problem in many cases.

I use Notepad++ to remove theses hidden characters from my XML File. If you have Notepad++ then go to `Encoding -> Convert to UTF-8` or `Encoding -> Convert to UTF-8 Without BOM`.

Also, there are two things below which I think you should correct in your XML File

1. Remove the space between `-` and `3` in below line which makes it invalid URL

Change:

```
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans- 3.0.xsd
```

To:

```
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
```

.

2. In your case, do not use `</bean>` to end the `<bean>` Tag

Change:

```
    <bean id="restaurantBean" class="com.gontuseries.springcore.Restaurant">  </bean>
```

To:

```
    <bean id="restaurantBean" class="com.gontuseries.springcore.Restaurant" />
```

Comment: It worked :) I just have to change my class path file ! Is that only the directory to in which my xml is saved?

Comment: Yes :) And I'm glad it worked for you. If this answer helped you then please accept it.

Comment: I was going to but could you tell me.. I got an error that tells me to change the class path.  As the xml file I posted is an example would the class path only be the spe8ng configuration. Xml directory path?

Comment: how to do this in eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you have some characters(white space for example) after `</beans>.`